# Create a list, vector or array with 4 cities and a temperature for each city

Tags: c#, linear-search

I can't get this program to work properly. We're supposed to through user input create a list, vector or array with 4 cities and a temperature for each city, I've successfully managed to add the cities and the temperature, also we have to keep the temperature between -60 and +60 which I've also successfully done. Last part of the program is that the user is supposed to input a temperature to search for, if the temperature exists for one of the cities it's supposed to write the temperature, the city that has the temperature and the index in the array/vector/list. I've decided to make it into a list as I thought that was easiest (maybe I'm wrong?). I seemingly can't get the linearsearch to work though as it always does the "return -1" part and just says the temperature the user is searching for doesn't exist in any index.

I've tried switching the names around if there is something I've done wrong there but that either breaks everything or gives the same result. I've tried to change the names and I've tried to get the linearsearch to use other variables to see if I may have mislabeled something but that just breaks the program when it reaches that point in the code. I've also tried to move codeblocks around in order to see if it tries to access it in wrong order but it yields the same result.

I'm a beginner at programming and I'm really worthless at working with several classes and constructors but since this is homework I kinda have to. Also the ToSpring(); that we must have in the code, everyone in the course just did what I did since it seems obsolete? Maybe there is something there I'm doing wrong? Maybe the constructor itself but I've taken it from our course literature? Not sure if it's valid info but I use Visual Studio 2022.

I hope the Swedish doesn't throw everyone off too much, I've tried to add comments in English to describe what it's supposed to be or do. "Stad" means city in Swedish btw if that clears up or helps in any way since that is a large part of the constructor and class?

```
class Stad
{
    public string name;
    public int temp;

    public Stad()
    {
    }

    public Stad(string name, int temp)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public int Temp
    {
        get { return temp; }
        set { temp = value; }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}


class Program
{

    static int LinearSearch(List<Stad> myList, int n) // linear search creation
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Stad.Count; i++)
        {
            if (myList[i].Temp == n)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Stad> myList = new List<Stad>(); // list for cities and temperature
        Stad myStad = new Stad();

    Stad_1: // city 1

        Console.WriteLine("Ange stad nummer 1"); // user input for city
        myStad.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ange temperatur för stad nummer 1"); // user input for temp 
        myStad.Temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (myStad.Temp >= 61) // what happens if temp is higher than 60 degrees
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_1;
        }
        else if (myStad.Temp <= -61) // what happens if temp is lower than -60 degrees
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_1;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ange stad nummer 2");
        }
        
    Stad_2: // see city 1 for details

        myStad.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ange temperatur för stad nummer 2");
        myStad.Temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (myStad.Temp >= 61)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_2;
        }
        else if (myStad.Temp <= -61)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_2;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ange stad nummer 3");
        }
                    
    Stad_3: // see city 1 for details

        myStad.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ange temperatur för stad nummer 3");
        myStad.Temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (myStad.Temp >= 61)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_3;
        }
        else if (myStad.Temp <= -61)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_3;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ange stad nummer 4");
        }
        
    Stad_4: // see city 1 for details

        myStad.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ange temperatur för stad nummer 4");
        myStad.Temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (myStad.Temp >= 61)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_4;
        }
        else if (myStad.Temp <= -61)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            goto Stad_4;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tack");
        }

        // what temp to search for in the linear search

        Console.Write("Ange temperatur att söka efter: ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine(); 
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(str);

        int list = LinearSearch(myList, n);

        // linear search printout

        if (list == -1)
            Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen finns ej");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Staden med temperaturen " + n + " finns på index " + list + " och är " + myList[list].Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `goto Stad_1;` No no no no ..... use loops. Forget that C#/.NET supports labels and goto.

Comment: `goto` is widely regarded as bad practice to use in code, because it makes your code flow 'jumpy' and hard to follow.  In the future, try to avoid using `goto` at all.

Comment: You never add to the list. So you are searching on an empty list. Which will always fail.

Comment: Well like I said I'm a newbie at this, so I would prefer to avoid the "goto" but it seems easiest to do and it's an introduction course but I will change it thanks.

Searching an empty list, I thought about that but I couldn't find any way to add to the list without breaking everything. Thanks, I shall work on this when I get home. 

I appreciate all your input people

Comment: Don't feel bad being a newbie. Every "Rockstar" programmer was in those shoes, at some point. Our reaction to the "goto"s may have seemed harsh, but it's really more like a parent watching a child about to touch something dangerous ;D Not that you are a child, but you get the gist. It's really well-meaning. But it's also ok to make mistakes. It's those you learn the most from.

Comment: I didn't feel bad about it, I understand you all mean't well so it's all good :) I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

I will not just present you a complete solution, since this is obviously course work.

But I'll give you some points to work on / with.

1. Do not use "goto". Use loops instead. Best forget, that it is supported at all.
   I'll give an example further down on how to avoid goto.

   > "goto" is a simple way to mess up even simple code to the point of where it becomes unreadable and not maintainable any more. That's why a lot of C# Devs refrain from using it *at all*. In fact, I have been coding C# about 20 years now, and have *never* used one single goto in production code. BUT of course, it has its place. Only that's not in simple every-day code. If you want to use it, you should have a very good reason to do so. So, this is a bit of a "learn to crawl before you can walk" thing.
2. Using `Convert.ToInt32(userInput)` will crash your program if the user input is not parsable. Use `int.TryParse` instead.
3. The actual problem at hand is: You create Stad instances, but you never add them to the list.

So what I would do (while keeping it simple) is this:

1. Split up your "data entry" part.

```
List<Stad> myList = new List<Stad>();
for( int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++ ) // 4 times ...
{
    myList.Add(GetStadFromUser()); // ... ask for a Stad and add it to your list.
}

// The Rest of your code should work now.
```

where GetStadFromUser is:

```
public static Stad GetStadFromUser()
{
    var stad = new Stad();
    do
    {
        // Get stad.Name with Console.ReadLine(); 
    } while(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stad.Name)); // Name should be not empty

    do
    { 
        // Ask User for Temperature
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if(!int.TryParse(userInput, out int temperature)) // could not be parsed
        {
             // TODO: User input was not a number => Tell him
             continue; // Try again
        }
        else if( /*check temperature too high || too low*/ )
        {
             // TODO: Temperature out of range => Tell user and ...
             continue; // try again
        }
        else
        {
             stad.Temperature = temperature;
             break; // Success => break out of loop
        }
    }
    while(true); 
    // Stad is complete, now return it:
    return stad;
}
```

You can find similar patterns to achieve the same with nearly any kind of loop. You can use do/while, while, for, ... maybe if you already had various types of loops, you can play around and try if you can switch between them. "Refactoring" can be a good way to learn, especially when to use what form of loop.

---

One last thing: You wondered, why you never had a hit in the search.
What I would have done to find the error:

```
static int LinearSearch(List<Stad> myList, int n) // linear search creation
{
    // vv This would have told you, your list is empty.
    Console.WriteLine("Performing search on List of size: {0}", myList.Count)
    for (int i = 0; i < Stad.Count; i++)
    {
        if (myList[i].Temp == n) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And it's a good idea to take the time and get familiar with breakpoints and the debugger, which in Visual Studio really is a piece of cake.

You may want to look into: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fdebugger%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2022)

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer earlier but I had too much to do yesterday. I really appreciate this thank you very much, I owe you one. I haven't been a member long enough so I'm not allowed to upvote just yet but: +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this revised Program.Main and new, extrapolated, InputCity method.

I replaced the 4 (almost identical) blocks to input city data with a loop and the new reusable method.

I also fixed the original usage of Convert.ToInt32 with a proper int.TryParse (only inside InputCity).

And finally, the new loop now adds cities to myList.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Stad> myList = new List<Stad>(); // list for cities and temperature

    const int NumCities = 4;
    for (int ixCity = 1; ixCity <= NumCities; ixCity++)
    {
        Stad myStad = InputCity(ixCity);
        myList.Add(myStad);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Tack");

    // what temp to search for in the linear search

    Console.Write("Ange temperatur att söka efter: ");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(str);

    int list = LinearSearch(myList, n);

    // linear search printout

    if (list == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen finns ej");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Staden med temperaturen " + n + " finns på index " + list + " och är " + myList[list].Name);
}

private static Stad InputCity(int ixCity)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ange stad nummer {0}", ixCity); // user input for city
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ange temperatur för stad nummer {0} ([{1}])", ixCity, name); // user input for temp 

        int temp;
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT A NUMBER");
            continue;
        }
        if (temp >= 61) // what happens if temp is higher than 60 degrees
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            continue;
        }
        if (temp <= -61) // what happens if temp is lower than -60 degrees
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt värde var god välj en siffra mellan -60 och +60");
            continue;
        }

        Stad myStad = new Stad();
        myStad.name = name;
        myStad.Temp = temp;
        return myStad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this. Sorry it took me a long time to answer but I didn't have time to look into it yesterday. I truly owe you one. Since I'm not allowed to upvote as I've not been member long enough: +1